# Update html table at a specific interval

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am new to PHP and Ajax. In my project I need to update a html table (for example each row of the table will contain the room name and current room  temperature. I need to update the temperature values in each row at a specific interval).

The backend MySQL table will contain the current temperature values of each rooms. The webpage is based on bootstrap3. The number of rows is dynamically generated by my PHP code.

How can I update these values (each row) at a specific time interval?

Comment: Do an ajax call and refresh or regenerate the table, simple as the question.

Comment: Use `setInterval` to run the AJAX refresh procedure every N seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how**

Jquery

```
setInterval(function(){

    $.get("get_my_updated_values.php" , function(result){

    $("#my_table_tbody").html(result); // my_table_tbody is the id of the body of your table. 

    });

 }, 3000);
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "my_table_tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

PHP (get_my_updated_values.php)

```
<?php

// some php to retrieve the data from your database 

echo '<tr>
            <td>New data 1</td>
            <td>new data 2</td>
        </tr>';

?>
```

it will refresh after every 3 seconds ... Its the exact thing you want ... Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to update certain aspects of my web page:

```
<div id="header-wrapper"><span class="pull-right label label-default" id="header-count"><?php echo $count; ?></span></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $header = $("#header-wrapper");

    setInterval(function () {

        $header.load("test.php #header-count");

    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```